# Is there a way to filter which Form records are shown with Query results?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a JobTicket table with all of our required production info, and a ScheduledItems table with all of our job ticket data, plus the dates to run that Job.

I get all the necessary data. My issue comes when I would like to do the opposite.

I created a Query to search for the Sales Order Number from both tables, and then set the criteria for Scheduled Items to null so it will only show the unscheduled Jobs. Query works, shows me all jobs that have not been Scheduled yet.

How do I filter my Form JobTicket to show only those unscheduled Jobs. I don't want to give my coworker those Query results to search Jobs one by one. Some days we can get 25+ Jobs with 10+ Line Items, so 250 manual searches.

Access query

```
SELECT 
    Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number,      
    Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number   
FROM Qry_JobTicket 
LEFT JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems 
ON    Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number   
    WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number) Is Null));
```

Comment: you join the tables by their corresponding  columns and ass ad were clause see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/perform-joins-using-access-sql

Comment: @nbk I understand joins already, my issue is I don't quite understand how I would go about using the query I have written to filter the form records. I would like to have a button my users could click and have it show only records that don't also exist in my ScheduledItems table. I will post the SQL of my query below this if you'd like to see it for whatever reason, but joins are not my problem. It's more I don't know how I would go about using the query results to only show those records that aren't also in ScheduledItems table.

Comment: that is not a good question for here but you can take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-datasheet-into-a-form-8a14cecd-7459-47df-9d46-10ee26c2fd1b and follow the steps

Comment: Can you use the [Form.Filter property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.filter(property)) to filter your form's records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have figured out how to go about it, all though I am sure it's not the best in the way of design principles. Here goes:

After creating the Query (SQL shown above, Qry_UnscheduledList) to find all of the Un-Scheduled Jobs, I created another query that brought in my Qry_JobTicket and my Qry_UnscheduledList. I inner joined on Sales Order Number, so we only see the Jobs yet to be scheduled, and brought in every field from Qry_JobTicket. Once that was done, I then created a button on my form and inserted the code below to change the Form's Record Source, similarly to as @HansUp suggested with the FormFilter property.

```
Private Sub Btn_ToBeScheduled_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm_JobTicket"
    With Forms("Frm_JobTicket")
        If .RecordSource = "Qry_JobTicket" Then
        .RecordSource = "Qry_ToBeScheduled"
        ElseIf .RecordSource = "Qry_ToBeScheduled" Then
        .RecordSource = "Qry_JobTicket"
            End If
            End With

End Sub
```

Now as I said earlier this may not be the best designing, but I was doing research for about an hour and couldn't find very many people who needed to filter their FormA records based off of corresponding records **that don't exist** in their FormB.